# Why Time complexity of Breadth First Search is O(V+E)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

When it should actually be O(E) Since E ranges from V-1 to V(V-1)/2 in a graph ? 
Why is BFS time complexity O(E+v).

It is said in CLRS that O(V) comes from enqueue and dequeue operations for every vertex , since V vertices exist it is O(1) * V = O(V). But the doubt is that is when all the V vertices are in use that is in a fully connected graph but in connected graph E=V-1 in the minimum case so Shouldnt it be O(E) rather than O(V+E)?

Comment: You should ask this question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/. This is really the type of question that I think would be better suited for that community.

Comment: Anyway, intuitively, it's O(V+E) because you don't really know, a priori, how many edges your graph will have (i.e. if your graph is sparse or full), but you know you will visit both all your edges and vertices.

Comment: @nbro What i understand is , only the vertices which are connected to the initial vertices are queued or if it comes to that matter dequeued so , and for any connected graph , e=v-1 (minimum case) , so shouldnt O(v+E) converge to O(e)? sparse graphs are not connected , still only graph that is considered is the one which is connected from source vertex . so still it should be O(E) right?

Comment: Sparse graphs are not necessarily disconnected. What do you mean "shouldn't O(V+E) converge to O(E)"? Anyway, O(E) is incorrect because you may just have 1 edge in all your graph, but you still have to visit all your vertices (i.e. you restart the BFS from each separate vertex).

Comment: @nbro Isn't that breadth first traversal? ,I thought BFS is only for connected graphs , and BFT is for disconnected graphs and All the algorithms i've seen also emphasized on the same point . And you might argue that initial setup of vertices need O(v) Time but from my point of view Can't u do that while traversing across all the edges and only mark connected vertices ? which are obviously is greater than |E|+1

Answer (score 1):

For complexity + is somewhat equivalent to max (See Dukeling@'s comment).
In a way you are right. For regular connected graphs you can assume it will be O(E) since you'll have more edges than vertices.

However, let's take a graph with no edges.
The BFS loop will not do anything, however as part of the setup you need to initialize the visited vector (maybe some more additional info that your implementation might need) which has V elements, so O(V).

Since we don't know what kind of graph we get, the correct way of expressing the complexity if O(V+E).

Comment: I wouldn't say `+` "actually means" `max`, but rather that they're equivalent, because `max(x,y) <= x+y <= 2*max(x,y)`.

Comment: @Sorin  What i understand is , we can ditch that initial coloring step by , coloring while traversing across edges and marking the node discovered , In this way we only color the Vertices V' in the subgraph that is connected to the original node , so V' will once again be around E and thus makes time complexity O(E) Doesnt it? Why color all the vertices initially when they are not even connected?

Comment: @jeshwanthchowdary It's not strictly about initial coloring, though you probably initialize the vector somehow to make sure you don't accidentally get some vertices incorrectly colored. At the very least, you need to allocate memory for the coloring. Even though you don't allocate each bool in an operation but in fairly large blocks, overall the operation is linear (with a very low constant).

Answer (score 0):

What you say it's true, but we have to consider the fact that BFS has an initialization phase into which you assign to all vertices distance +inf, color white and father NULL.

This initial step can't be skipped because BFS visits only the vertices that are reachable from the source, but it could receive as input a disconnected graph and you have to compute for each vertex the information about distance and father.